# git pre-commit hook fails when pushing to remote repo

Tags: git, hook

pre-commit works fine and shows expected output when `git commit`. But when I executed `git push`, I found files and codes in the remote repo were in fact not processed through pre-commit file.

Is there anything I miss or did I understand the whole hooks mechanism wrong?

Comment: Do all committers have to hooks enabled?

Comment: I'm still in a testing phase, so I'm the only commiter

Comment: I found that pre-commit was executed and returned no error, `git` entered into commit phase. But the weired thing is, codes commit into local repo was something that haven't been processed by pre-commit. So here `git status` shows diff changed by pre-commit. I wonder should `git commit` commits result processed by pre-commit?

Comment: `git push` pushes commits; it does not run the pre-commit hook. Commits, once made, *cannot be changed* in any way. At most, you can decide that some commit is no good and simply stop using it, perhaps adding a new-and-improved substitute using `git commit --amend` (which despite the argument does not change the old commit, it just makes a new-and-improved one to use instead).